# Why do I get the error "Unable to update the password" when calling AzMan?

Tags: c#, winforms, authorization, adam, azman

I'm doing a authorization check from a WinForms application with the help of the AzMan authorization provider from Enterprise Library and am receiving the the following error:

> Unable to update the password. The value provided as the current password is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007052B) (Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Security.AzMan)
>
> ---
>
> Unable to update the password. The value provided as the current password is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007052B) (Microsoft.Interop.Security.AzRoles)

The AzMan store is hosted in ADAM on another computer in the same domain. Other computers and users do not have this problem. The user making the call has read access to both ADAM and the AzMan store. The computer running the WinForms app and the computer running ADAM are both on Windows XP SP2.

I've had access problems with AzMan before that I've resolved, but this is a new one... What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out from the event log that there was a security issue with the user making the call to AzMan from a remote computer. The user did not belong the local Users group on the computer running ADAM/AzMan. When I corrected that everything worked again.

Answer (score 2):

For AzMan with ASP.NET, turn on impersonation in `web.config` (`<identity impersonate="true" username="xx" pasword="xx" />`), and make sure with an AD administrator that the impersonation account has "reader" permissions on the AzMan store; plus, give write permissions to this account on the `Temporary ASP.NET Files` folder (under `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\<framework>`).

Comment: The error occurred in a WinForms application so this answer does not apply to context of the question.